# remove specific html tags using php

Tags: php, html

Since I dont want to use stip_tags function of php instead of I want to replace  `<script> and </script>` to empty string so that output should be alert(1).

> Input:- 
>   `<script>alert(1)</script>`
>
> Output:- alert(1)

how to achieve it.

Answer (score 15):

Either use a simple replace:

```
$string = str_replace(array("<script>","</script>"), "");
```

or a RegEx:

```
$string = preg_replace("/<script.*?>(.*)?<\/script>/im","$1",$string);
```

Comment: Be careful: The regex does not recognize new lines. Add the `s`-flag (`/ims`) to fix that.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to prevet XSS attacks, you shouldn't *merely* worry about `script` tags, someone might exploit it like this: `<a href="http://anywhere.com" onClick="alert(1);">test</a>` (this is a *very* basic way though).

If you only want the `script` tag, with no attributes, to be filtered:

```
str_replace(array('<script>', '</script>'), array('', ''), $str);
```

You should improve this using Regex; using preg_match'es and preg_replaces (or only preg_replaces) you can match and/or replace the script tag with its attributes. Or even have more protection against XSS.

Edit: or even a regex like `/<script>(.+)<\/script>/` then store what between the brackets into a variable then print it.

Answer (score 2):

Easy way is using **StripTags**.

go to [StripTags github](https://github.com/mimrahe/StripTags) and download or install via composer.
this class has a method called `only` that do this for you!

```
use Mimrahe\StripTags\Stripper;
$stripper = new Stripper();
$stripper->text('<a href="#">link</a><p>some paragraph</a>');
$stripper->only(['p']);
echo $stripper->strip(); // prints '<a href="#">link</a>some paragraph'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this comrade..

```
$strn = "<script>alert(1)</script>";
$ptrn = "=^<script>(.*)</script>$=i";

echo preg_match( $ptrn, $strn, $mtchs ); // 0 means fail to matche and 1 means matches was found!
var_dump( $mtchs );
```

results in

```
1array(2) { 
    [0]=> string(25) "" 
    [1]=> string(8) "alert(1)" 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can always use `strip_tags()` with a second parameter containing the allowable tags.

Alternativly, use...

```
preg_replace('/<script>(.*)</script>/i', '$1', $input);
```

Note, not tested.

Comment: So add the tags you don't want to remove to the second parameter.

Comment: Don't make me repeat myself :/

Answer (score -2):

```
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><strong><a>');
```

Just state the ones you dont want removed in the second param

Comment: Doesn't solve the issue. Would remove the node inside the tags. The example shows stripping the tags, but not the contents.

Comment: -1 Doesn't address the question at all. First off, OP said `"I dont want to use stip_tags"`. Secondly, what if this were stripping tags for an entire html file? It is completely unreasonable to expect an entirely comprehensive list of all possible html tags to exist.